# How can I merge these regex into one?

Tags: python, html, regex, tags, expression

(Before I start: I'm doing this in python)

So basically I need my single regex to match all quotation marks immediately before and after my html QUOT tags: If a quotation mark exists in those spaces, I need it to match.

Example:

```
<QUOT.START> Hello, this doesn't match! <\QUOT.END> 

"<QUOT.START> "Hello, this will call 4 matches! " <\QUOT.END> "
```

I have 4 different regexes for this purpose:

```
1.   \"+(?=<QUOT\.START>)

2.   (?<=<QUOT\.START>)\"+

3.   \"+(?=<\\QUOT\.END>)

4.   (?<=<\\QUOT\.END>)\"+
```

Can I merge these 4 into basically one?

Comment: Just combine your regexes and put a pipe character between them `|`

Comment: @ctwheels welp I knew there had to be some sort of syntax for that, thanks! :D

Comment: You're welcome :) if that works for you, post a solution and accept it on your own post, nothing wrong with that here

Comment: How do I do that? just "answer your question" at the bottom of the page? New to stack overflow.

Comment: Are you using the newer `regex` module?

Comment: @MiguelSáLemos should say `Answer your question` on a blue button

Comment: Yep! Should say `Answer your question` on a blue button

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) (which supports infinite lookbehind) you can somewhat condense your expression to

```
(?<=<\\?QUOT\.(?:START|END)>[\t ]*)" # matches quotes after <quot.start> or <quot.end>
                                     # plus whitespaces, eventually
|
"(?=[\t ]*<\\?QUOT\.(?:START|END)>)  # before <quot.start> or <quot.end>,
                                     # plus whitespaces eventually
```

---

Without verbose mode:

```
(?<=<\\?QUOT\.(?:START|END)>[\t ]*)"|"(?=[\t ]*<\\?QUOT\.(?:START|END)>)
```

---

Generally speaking this is:

```
(?<=<tag><whitespaces, eventually>)quote|quote(?=<whitespaces, eventually><tag>)
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import regex as re

string = """
<QUOT.START> Hello, this doesn't match! <\QUOT.END> 
"<QUOT.START> "Hello, this will call 4 matches! " <\QUOT.END> "
"""

rx = re.compile(r'''(?<=<\\?QUOT\.(?:START|END)>[\t ]*)"|"(?=[\t ]*<\\?QUOT\.(?:START|END)>)''')

for m in rx.finditer(string):
    print(m.group(0))
    print(m.span())
```

This brings up four quotes and their positions.

Answer (score 1):

@ctwheels helped me figure out this (super simple) solution: Being a total newbie at regexes, I didn't know about the |(pipe) syntax . So here is the final regex I wanted (And it works!)

```
\"+(?=<QUOT\.START>)|(?<=<QUOT\.START>)\"+|\"+(?=<\\QUOT\.END>)|(?<=<\\QUOT\.END>)\"+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = '<QUOT.START> "Hello, this will call 4 matches! " <\QUOT.END> '
import re
strings = re.findall('\"(.*?)\"', s)
```

Output:

```
['Hello, this will call 4 matches! ']
```